# Wiring diagram for laboratory-related aquarium equipment (PID, SSR..)

Tags: wiring, solid-state-relay, pid-controller, heater

I am currently in the process of constructing a "thermal aquarium chamber", used to study the responses of various species to warming temperatures in their aquatic environment.

The idea is to control a water heater (flow-through) via a ramp/soak PID (Auber SYL-2352P).

I have a very general question regarding the attached wiring diagram: **Is my wiring correct?** Is there anything I need to add or change? Have I overlooked something?

[image: Current wiring diagram with used equipment]

**Update for future visitors**

Just supplementing the original question for future visitors. I have tested the set-up (heating water from 20 °C to 30 °C in 0.3 °C/min-1 steps) and it worked. Here's a picture.

[image]

Comment: What is the 2nd plug for on the heater?

Comment: Which 2nd plug do you mean?

Comment: You only have one wire coming off the water heater, and it goes to a plug and you're solid state relay. You need two wires from your water heater?

Comment: What would the function of the second wire be? The water heater only has two wires by default. If that's an issue, could you explain why?

Comment: Exactly, where is the 2nd wire on your schematic. I see 1 wire comming from heater. Where is the 2nd on? To complete the circuit.

Comment: Ok I suddenly understand. The blue is one wire and the yellow is the 2nd one. I thought you were splitting a single wire. Yes everything looks good .

Comment: Oh now I see what you meant, I could have been more specific. Thanks for confirming :)

Comment: You might want to put some sort of electrically-insulating cover over the SSR connections - if water spills and someone slips then their hand could end up gripping it as they try to stop falling.

Comment: Yes, I've been thinking about that, too. I will cut a plastic container and cover the SSR with it sometime this week! Thanks for looking out

Answer (score 1):

Yes everything looks good.

I answered in comments, but here it is for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

Your wiring diagram is correct. It is essentially the same as the circuit in figure 7 of the manual for the PID controller (https://www.auberins.com/images/Manual/SYL-2352P%20Manual.pdf)

It is this:

[image]

I do recommend using only one plug instead of two like in your picture and adding power switch to AC power so that power can be switched off. 
Also to make this schematic clearer, you might want to make clear distinctions of wires and separate them with enough space from each other.

Comment: I read the manual, but as a complete novice, the technicality was overwhelming. I will go back to the lab today, incorporate the changes you suggested and update the wiring diagram. What is the advantage of having one plug instead of two? Thank you for your input.

Comment: Well if you use one plug then you save money and uses only outlet. You’re welcome. Good luck.